# Custom response for Web Application Firewall (WAF)

Tags: http, firewalls, waf

What should be the custom response code when WAF blocks a request due to matched rules or policy violation.
We should kept the response code as 403 or 200 when WAF returns a response against a blocked request. What is the general security practice and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way, however there is a code 401 "Unauthorized", 403 "Forbidden", or even the code 450 "Blocked by Windows Parental Controls" and I think cloudfare are using their own codes. My suggestion is don't bring too much information to the attacker about the reason and probably just reject with a 401 or something standard. Take into account that if you respond with a 4xx "Firewall blocked" the attacker will know that you are using a waf.

Comment: 401 is a bad choice. [It means](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1) lack of proper credentials which is not the case here. [403 Forbidden](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) looks like the better choice here, [400 Bad Request](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) would make sense too.